# NuGet project is targeted to NET Framework 4.5 by default. VS2010 asks to retarget Nuget project to NET Framework 4 on one of developer machines

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nuget, .net-framework-version

So, I have a Visual Studio 2010 solution with many projects including NuGet project in it.
I know that Visual Studio 2010 doesn't support NET Framework 4.5, that's not the question.

Strange thing is that if I open this solution on one computer, I get no warning message saying

> "The project  is targeting ".NETFramework,Version=4.5",
>   which is not installed on this machine. You must download this
>   framework in order to open and build this project. In order to
>   proceed, you must select and option below (retarget to NET Framework
>   4, download, leave project unloaded)".

On another machine I receive this message. I'm 100% sure that Framework 4.5 and SDK is installed on both.
If I choose "Retarget to 4.0" it will add this into "nuproj":

> ```
> <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
> <TargetFrameworkProfile />
> ```

So, my guess is that one machine is configured to target NET Framework 4.5 by default and another - to target 4.0 by default. Is there something like "machine.config" ? Why is this situation happening on one machine but not on another?
I want "NuGet" project to target NET Framework by default without adding "TargetFrameworkVersion" inside "nuproj" on both computers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

what's .nuproj? NuGet does not have the concept of its own project types. It works with visual studio project types.

Comment: *.nuproj is project file type that is created by "NuBuild Project System" Visual Studio extension. Basically it's used to create Nuget package right in Visual Studio.
Here is the link to that extension:
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3efbfdea-7d51-4d45-a954-74a2df51c5d0